# Why is tax_class_id reset to 0

Tags: magento-1.8, database, tax-class

I hope someone can help. We have a very strange problem. We found out that some products didn't have tax in the shop so we had a look in de backend. The right class is selected when editing a product but when I look in the database the `tax_class_id` is set to `0` while it should be `7` in this case. Also when I change it in the database and safe the product again by the magento backend it's again reset to `0`. I already tried to truncate and disable the flat products tables but it does not make a difference. The strange this is that there seems no difference in products that keep the `tax_class_id` at `7` and the ones that are reset to `0`.

We are using magento 1.8.1.0

Answer (score 1):

I found it myself. I seems that during the import the store-specific values are updated and do not use the "use default" anymore. I mass updated the products (per store view) with the correct values and now it works.